# How to config Nginx Only Support HTTP2 for No ALPN Clients

Tags: nginx, http2, http-1.1, alpn

Here is the situation:
Our client wants to back support some old ios mac systems, which the network lib it used does not support ALPN. Our Server is set up only to accept gRPC requests, so there is no need for the server to accept HTTP1.1 requests.

So how do I disable Nginx to accept HTTP1.1 request and only enable HTTP2 support and skip the ALPN?

I tried to make Nginx defaults to support http2 but it still involves the ALPN process.

Answer (score 0):

it seems nginx is do http2 based on ALPN so there is no walkaround for that.

Our customer request http2 only service because other product they use are using gRPC with envoy proxy. Envoy seems to have the ability to provide http2 only service without alpn, but it is subject to find out why ( as the document does not specify it clearly)